# load a tab content from independent file in web page

Tags: joomla, html

I am developing a joomla based website where i have a certain page as can be seen here.

http://www.careerpluss.com/portal/component/content/article/45/79-univvisits.html

here i have created 4 tabs city wise.

The whole code has been written in a single article (file).

For each tab, can i write it down in separate files (htmls) and load them here as we click on the tabs.

For e.g. i have the delhi visits tab. i want the whole code for this tab to be written in a separate file (delhi.htnl) and when i click on the delhi tab, the visits page should read the contents of this page and load it here.

Can this be done or is there a better solution to this?

PS: i need to give control to the client to modify the individual files and once uploaded in a specific location, the page displayed should have contents displayed here.

I hope i have made my requirement clear.

Kindly help me out here.

Regards

Comment: are you looking to delay the loading tabs until they are clicked on?

Comment: Not really. I want the tabs content to be placed in separate files which will be read from when displaying maintaining the tabs and the accordions.

Answer (score 0):

If you want these displayed in a different html file as you indicate I would suggest doing this with an iframe

http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp

```
<iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com"></iframe>
```

Comment: Thnx. But using iframes would i still be able to display the tabs and the accordions?

Comment: You can keep the tabs that is correct.  Or you can just seperate the html in different files and use an HTML include <!--#include virtual="path to file/include-file.html" -->

Answer (score 0):

Use [**Jumi**](http://extensions.joomla.org/extensions/edition/custom-code-in-content/1023) and do a php include file for each.